# Can I use the Bug Status report of agile template 2012 in scrum template? If not how to do?

Tags: tfs, reporting, ssrs-2012

Actually the bug status report of agile template is not worlking in scrum template of 2012? ANy way out to create or modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the `.rdl` file directly from the Report Server and edit it in the [Report Designer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), BIDS or SQL Server Data Tools BI or [Report Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29072). Since the MSF for Agile template uses a couple of fields that don't exist in the Scrum template (like priority) and since the status transitions differ between the Scrum Template and the Agile template you will have do to some work to ensure that the report can work with the Scrum template.

### Scrum Template

The [Scrum Bug status flow looks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731589%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ChangeState) like:

> New > Accepted  > Committed > Done

And the scrum template uses the "Related" link to link a bug to a PBI or other Bug workitem.

### Agile template

The [MSF Agile bug status flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380645%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CloseBugs) looks like:

> New > Active > Resolved > Closed

And the agile template uses the "Related" or the "Affects/Affected By" relation.

### Field Reference

[There is an extended index of all fields used by the different templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971.aspx). Some are shared, but each template also has a set of its own fields it uses.

Comment: status transition like ?

Comment: If any link  you know that would be great where I can find the information about how the data is stored in both the templates.

Comment: Updated with additional information on the transitions and field references.

Comment: any table you know where test case status and bug status is stored in the TFS_warehouse?

Comment: Check the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286682.aspx and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620635.aspx

Comment: And please Accept the question as answer if this answers your question.